# Is it possible to get a value from a specific cell depending on several dropdown-list values?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to create a program which extract values.

I have a bunch of data tables with specific values:

[image]

They are very similar to each other but the difference is the weight (3300 kg and 3500 kg) and altitude (0, 1000 feet and 2000 feet). I don't think I can combine them into one table.

On another sheet I have created 3 dropdown list where you can select temperature, altitude and weight - for example `"+15°C, 1000 feet, 3300 kg"`.

What I want to do is to extract the correct value from the correct data table and put it in a cell. For `"+15°C, 1000 feet, 3300 kg"` the correct value for CTOD would be **5** for example.

Any friendly soul who can point me in the right direction?

EDIT: I combined all values into one table as commented, see image 2.

[image]

Comment: Just wondering, why you say *I don't think I can combine them into one table*? You have same fields all the time, just add 2 extra fields with *Altitude* and *weight* and it would be a single table. Indeed, it's easier to use formulas on 1 single table than this, and also, you could benefit from advanced features as Pivot Tables. But as I said, just wondering...

Comment: There are different values depending on altitude and weight but still same temperature. That would mean same temperature will occur many times. I'm thinking of temperature like a unique ID but maybe that is wrong?

Comment: If you know how to use Pivot Tables, then temperarute occuring many times won't be a problem. Another option would be creating your own Unique ID combining weight, altitude and Temperature, because, according to your data, for a specific weight with a specific altitude and specific temperature, there is only 1 CTOD. But as I said, I think is better to repeat values in columns and then use Pivot Tables.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to use Pivot tables. I have edited my original post and created one table for all entries. Values can be the same, even CTOD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your data is in a single table, and you have specific parameters to filter and get a CTOD (in your case, those filters would be temperature, weight and Altitude) you can use the formula SUMIFS:

> **[SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)**

I've duplicated your data in a easy way, ignoring some columns. Then, I did 3 dropwdowns list, where I can choose parameters (`temperature`, `weight` and `Altitude`). Depending on selection, the formula will return one value or another.

[image]

As you can see, If I input `OAT=+15,` `Altitude=1000` and `Weight=3300`, formula will return `CTOD=5`.

The formula is:

```
=SUMIFS($D$2:$D$28;$A$2:$A$28;G6;$B$2:$B$28;H6;$C$2:$C$28;I6)
```

I've uploaded a sample file to my Google Drive. if you want to download it and check the formula by yourself.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1K7X14MuM84VH-7-nnMzGDfYs9Whjp-8-

Please, note this formula works because every single line is right. I there were duplicates (let's say there is twice the data relative to weight 3300, Temperature +15 and Altitude 1000), then the formula would return `CTOD=10` (twice because the duplicate). **So be careful with that.**

Comment: This is amazing @Foxfire And Burns And Burns, I really appreciate it! I believe this works as planned. I might need to create a few more dropdowns and in that case I just add statements in the formula? 

EDIT: You mean if there are two rows with temp 15, altitude 1000 and weight 3300?

Comment: Thanks, if this answer worked for you, please mark it as correct, so the question can be closed. About your questions,yes :) just add some statements and it will work **if you add them properly**. Read the link I provided about the formula, because you need to dominate it if you want to add statements. It's easy. About second question, yes, I mean if there are 2 rows wth temp 15, alt 1000 and weight 3300.